# How do I consider an cell array image as an input of blockproc?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, biometrics

```
function block = block_partion(image, size_of_theblock)  

image = cellfun(@(x)((x-mean(x(:)))./std(double(x(:)))),image, 'UniformOutput',false);
fun = @(block_struct) std2(block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data));

block = blockproc(image, [size_of_theblock size_of_theblock],fun);
end
```

This is the error that i get:

Error using blockproc>parse_inputs (line 997)
Invalid input image.  The input image to BLOCKPROC should be either a numeric matrix, a string filename, or an
ImageAdapter object.  See the documentation for BLOCKPROC for a list of readable file formats and their
extensions.  See the documentation for ImageAdapter for information on making ImageAdapter objects.

Comment: You can't.  `blockproc` expects its processing function to accept a numeric matrix, not a cell array.  Are you **dead set** on using `blockproc`? There is a way to do this code without using `blockproc`. You are trying to perform standardization on image blocks in your code. You can do this without `blockproc`.  If you are not bound to `blockproc` I can write an answer.

Comment: Thanx, actually it's possible using the following line:                           blockfun = @(x) blockproc(x, [size_of_theblock size_of_theblock],  fun);
    block = cellfun(blockfun,image, 'UniformOutput', false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blockfun = @(x) blockproc(x, [size_of_theblock size_of_theblock],  fun);
block = cellfun(blockfun,image, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Thanx, replacing this lines in the code it works well!